# How to run a SQL statement periodically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I have a "raw" SQL statement that I need to execute in order to update status of objects (something like `UPDATE users SET status=1 WHERE <some conditions>`.

I need this to always run after every 60 seconds in the background.

How do I do this?

Ps. The environment is Ubuntu 10.10 and Rails 3.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a cron (crontab) to periodically call a Rail script doing this update.

Comment: But how to do it? Also, will the entire Rails environment be loaded every 60 seconds just to run the query? Any example you can give?

Comment: I've bookmarked once this tuto: http://www.ameravant.com/posts/recurring-tasks-in-ruby-on-rails-using-runner-and-cron-jobs may be useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Loading rails environment to run one sql statement is a huge waste of resources.

Crontab for mysql:

```
0 * * * * mysql your_db_name -e "users SET status=1 WHERE <some conditions>;"
```

Crontab for PostgreSQL:

```
0 * * * * psql  -c "users SET status=1 WHERE <some conditions>" your_db_name
```

You may have to set PATH variable at the top of your crontab file to make sure that mysql/psql commands resolve.

Hope this helps.